# Flyway:init doesn't create schema database

Tags: mysql, maven, flyway

I'm using flyway to manage a multi-schema database in mysql and I've configured flyway using Maven. I have listed a database called 'metadata' as the first in the `<schemas>` tag so flyway will put the `schema_version` table here. When I run `mvn flyway:migrate` I'm expecting this table **and the `metadata`** database to be created. Flyway 2.1.1 tries to create the table, but does not create the database first so it fails.

```
[DEBUG] Schemas: metadata,temp,OTHER_DBS_REDACTED
[DEBUG] Schema `temp` already exists. Skipping schema creation.
[DEBUG] Database: MySQL 5.6  
[ERROR] com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error setting current sc
hema to `metadata`
[ERROR] Caused by com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unk
nown database 'metadata'
```

I thought `mvn flyway:init` might create the schemas, but that fails with a different but obviously related error.

```
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:2.1.1:init (default-cli) @ database ---
[INFO] Creating Metadata table: `metadata`.`schema_version`
[ERROR] com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE `metadata`.`schema_version` (
    `version_rank` INT NOT NULL,
    `installed_rank` INT NOT NULL,
    `version` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `script` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    `checksum` INT,
    `installed_by` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `installed_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `execution_time` INT NOT NULL,
    `success` BOOL NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
[ERROR] Caused by com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'metadata'
```

If I `create database metadata` then things proceed smoothly. I'm quite enjoying flyway in fact. Short of running some sql manually, is there a way to make flyway create this database? Is this simply a bug?

TIA

Comment: Good question, I'm currently having exactly the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now the create schema support is an all or nothing thing. If all schemas are missing, they all will be created, otherwise none will be created.

Comment: Ah! This was the lynchpin. I had listed 'temp' as a schema to manage and it already exists in the DB by default. **Removing** this from the schema list allowed flyway to create the databases and the schema_version table.